# javascript unable to get style after setting css class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a cell class

```
  .cell {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
  }
```

In my createCell function:

```
  var createCell = function(id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = id;
    div.className = 'cell';
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
      div.style.background = pickedColor;
    });
    document.getElementById('gridArea').appendChild(div);
  }
```

as you can see, i have already assigned className to 'cell'. After calling this function, I call

```
document.getElementById(id).style.width
```

It returns empty string ""

Why is it so? how can I retrieve the value immediately after assigning the className?

Comment: Rolled back your question, please don't modify the code in the question otherwise an answer which was originally valid will look invalid. If it didn't fix the issue comment on the answer or add the updated code below the question.

Comment: Because `.style` is only for the `styles` directly on that element, styles from a class doesn't count in that case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get Styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172871/javascript-get-styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get styles that come from CSS. `.style` just accesses the style attributes of the DOM element.

```
width = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(id)).width;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign the id parameter the the id of the actual element anywhere.

What you need to do is this,

`div.id = id`

**Edit 1**

You need to use `getComputedStyle`.

`alert(getComputedStyle(div).width);`

The JSFiddle shows how.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvohdnbn/

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying goal is to access the width of the element, you should use its .offsetWidth property.

`style.width` will only have a value if one has been set using the `style` attribute, not via the application of CSS classes.

Try `document.getElementById(yourIdHere).offsetWidth`